# PHP SQLSRV Driver Error

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, eclipse-plugin, sqlsrv

I'm debugging a script in Eclipse that makes a call to the sqlsrv_connect() function. My development environment was setup using the Zend Server CE.  When I installed I checked the option to include the driver and verified it was installed properly using the PHPInfo page.  The below snippet shows my registered PHP Streams, you can see that sqlsrv is in there

```
Registered PHP Streams:     https, ftps, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, phar, sqlsrv
```

However, when debugging and I hit a line that makes a call to sqlsrv_connect(), I get the error:

```
Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

I don not understand why this is happening.  Are there some configurations in Eclipse that need to be adjusted?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that eclipse is using different PHP instance than you webserver. And that instance does not have sqlsrv extension enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely new to PHP and I am having the exact same problem.   I can use the sqlsrv driver through IIS as well as through the command line.  But when debugging in eclipse, the sqlsrv driver is not loaded.

I am going to have to give up on Sql Server for this solution if I cannot figure this out, because I have to be able to debug.